# Nginx deleted file still downloads

Tags: nginx, filesystems

**Scenario:**

- Create a random file (1024M in this case) `dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1M count=1024`
- Initiate download (`curl src > /dev/null`)
- Delete the file from the server
- Curl still downloads `100%, 1024M`

How is this possible, if the file **is** deleted on the server?

The server has `512M` RAM and *no* SWAP, the file could not have been read all to RAM. Therefore, it must have read from disk at some point. However, the file stopped existing mid way through the download, so how come nginx still lets people continue the download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the download starts, the webserver opens the source file, and won't close it until all the data is sent.  Deleting a file won't stop a process that has the file open from reading and writing to it.  Only once the process closes the file will it be deleted by the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

True: the datablocks (and the inode) are released when the linkcount gets 0 AND no proces has the file open.